# How to fix smooth scrolling issues in a UITableView with custom view controllers in headers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have created a tableview in such a way that all the rows are of 0 height but with custom headers. I am displaying different view controllers in different headers. I am able to parse the table properly but when I scroll down, it doesn't scroll smoothly.
The view controllers I added in the headers are mostly collection view and page view controllers, which display images.
What can I do to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use the cells first instead of the headers? If you don't provide code, or illustrate better the question or provide hipotesys at least you won't get many answers i guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is really tough without any code, but understand these principles of a UITableView:

1. Every time you show a cell or header that includes a view controller or view that hasn't been instantiated, it creates that on the main thread which is also doing the scrolling, hence the lag time.
2. UICollectionViewControllers and UIPageViewController are EXTREMELY heavy classes that take a lot of time to instantiate and setup. I would recommend NOT putting them in a UITableView unless you have to and if you do, make sure you're only instantiating one of them per cell and not recreating them each time.
3. Loading images can also take quite some time if not done asynchronously, especially depending on where you're getting them from. Offload as much as you can onto separate threads.